# DateSub function based on other field integer in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to compute someone's birth year based on the age and the date it was entered into our system. How do I use the Date_Sub function using the age field as my interval?

```
UPDATE `test.table` 
SET BirthYear = DATE_SUB(DateEntered, INTERVAL Age YEAR) 
WHERE BirthYear IS NULL;
```

When I try this query I get the following error:

```
Interval value must be coercible to INT64 type at [2:50]
```

I've tried casting the Age field as an INT64:

```
No matching signature for function DATE_SUB for argument types: DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [2:21]
```

My Table looks like this where the BirthYear and DateEntered are DateTime and the Age field is a string:

```
BirthYear   DateEntered          Age
NULL        2016-09-18T04:00:00  10
NULL        2020-09-18T00:00:00  7
NULL        2018-03-08T00:00:00  6.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use DATETIME_SUB instead

```
DATETIME_SUB(DateEntered, INTERVAL SAFE_CAST(SAFE_CAST(Age AS FLOAT64) AS INT64) YEAR)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you

Comment: After validating my data, it looks like this query isn't computing the half years correctly. For example, if the age is 0.5 and the date it was entered in was 2019-12-19T02:01:00
the result should be 2019 for the birth year. Except this queries output is 2018. Any thoughts?

Comment: depends on what rounding logic you need you should adjust age before casting to int. you can for example use `age + 0.5` or use respective functions like FLOOR, CEILING, etc.!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess I'm not sure the best way to round the age field because if the age is for example 6.5 = 6 years and 6months old. I tried `DATETIME_SUB(DateEntered, INTERVAL SAFE_CAST(SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(Age)as FLOAT64) as INT64) YEAR)`  but there are still discrepancies. Do I need to convert the age to months?

Comment: this is not quite possible to address all the new aspects of your case within the comments. I would suggest to post new question with all new details, logic and rules you want to follow along with examples of input data and expected output. If you do so, we will be able to help you further. But current question is fully answered already, so let's leave it as is and move ourselves into new post :o)